# How to get `page_fan_adds` for multiple days using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I can get the value of `page_fan_adds` for a specific date using FQL.

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id = XXX AND 
metric = "page_fan_adds" AND end_time = end_time_date("2012-07-20") AND 
period = period("day")
```

And I get:

```
{"data": [
    {"metric": "page_fan_adds", 
      "value": 1}
]}
```

However, using Graph API, I can get data for a period of one month: `graph.facebook.com/XXX/insights/page_fan_adds/?since= 1340175600&until=1342767600`. And I get:

```
{"data": [
  {"id": "XXX/insights/page_fan_adds/day", 
   "name": "page_fan_adds", 
   "period": "day", 
   "values": [
     {"value": 4, 
      "end_time": "2012-06-21T07:00:00+0000"}, 
     {"value": 2, 
      "end_time": "2012-07-20T07:00:00+0000"}
  ], 
  "title": "Daily New Likes", 
  "description": "Daily The number of new people who have liked your Page (Total Count)"}], 
"paging": {
  "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/XXX/insights/page_fan_adds/?since=1337583600&until=%201340175600", 
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/XXX/insights/page_fan_adds/?since=1342767600&until=1345359600"
  }
}
```

`period` column can only be `day` for `page_fan_adds`. So how to get one month's data using FQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only way to do this by querying all the dates separately and then aggregating them.

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=XXX AND 
   metric = "page_fan_adds" AND period = period("day") AND (
      end_time = end_time_date("2012-07-20") OR 
      end_time = end_time_date("2012-07-19") OR
      ...
      end_time = end_time_date("2012-06-21")
   )
```

Trying an `end_time IN` throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights 
WHERE object_id=XXX 
AND metric = "page_fan_adds" 
AND period = period("day") 
AND end_time in ( 
  end_time_date("2012-07-20"), 
  end_time_date("2012-07-19"), 
  end_time_date("2012-06-21")
)
```