# How to get page fan count from last week

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I want to get the number of new facebook fans for a given page from last week.

e.g.: monday to sunday of previous week.

I have searched for this but can't find any info.
I can get the total fan count easily from the social graph but not sure how to get new fan count from last week so that I can get a report like:

```
 New fans last week: 152
 Total fans: 2341
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be admin of that page, and you need the "read_insights" permission. Without user authorization you don´t have access to the Insights, and that´s the only way to get detailed statistics.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

Using FQL, it is explained here:

> [How to get `page_fan_adds` for multiple days using FQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746864/how-to-get-page-fan-adds-for-multiple-days-using-fql)

A bit complicated, because you have to add the daily values. But on the same page, the much easier solution is presented:

```
bladauhu/insights/page_fan_adds/?since=1340175600&until=1342767600
```